# My Microsoft lumia 535 Doesn`t Showing notification when its lock fromn last 1 week

Tags: 8.1

I purchased a Lumia 535 on april 15. Its good, but from last 4 days it's not showing missed calls, msg notification when its in lock position at the top. When I slide from top it shows missed call r msg came like that. But now it's not showing. What happened?

Comment: Try restarting your mobile once, if that doesnt work, do soft reset..

Comment: Don't do a reset. Do you have a PIN set?

Comment: Have you changed your lock screen apps?

Comment: Check your Lock screen settings and choose apps for lockscreen notifications.